# SQL Insert to table 2 column at a time on each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck on a problem where I need to insert data into a another table, but in a way that I insert 2 columns, then stay on the same row, insert the next 2 and so on.

I have the following table data

[image]

I have a table with 2 columns I want to fill but want data to be entered like:

```
Row 1:(Row1A,Row1B)
Row 2:(Row1C,Row1D)
Row 3:(Row1E,Row1D)
Row 4:(Row2A,Row2B)
Row 5:(Row2C,Row2D)
Row 6:(Row2E,Row2F)
```

I can achieve the above using a loop, however I want to know another way that can improve performance. Is there a way to achieve this?

Edit: Order needs to be correct. I will need the first row columns added to the table first before moving onto second row.

Comment: Does the order matter? Just use Insert Select statement with `UNION`. Select columns 1 and 2, UNION Select 3 and 4 UNION Select 5 and 6. Or am I missing something.

Comment: @WEI_DBA: `union all` instead of `union` :-)

Comment: `union` removes duplicates `union all` is the way to go

Comment: @dnoeth Agreed. Thanks!

Comment: Order does matter. If i use the select column 1 and 2 with union all approach, It will add the first 2 column first row then first 2 columns second row which is not what i am trying to achieve. I need the first row coulmns added before moving onto next row. Thanks

Comment: @Maz: There's no order in a relational table, but if you want to, you can run 3 Insert/Selects: Insert Select col1, col2; Insert Select col1, col2;Insert Select col1, col2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `apply`:

```
insert into t2(col1, col2)
    select col1, col2
    from data d cross apply
         (values (varchar1, varchar2), (varchar3, varchar4), (varchar5, varchar6)
         ) v(col1, col2);
```

Tables represent *unordered* sets.  Because you have exactly two columns, you don't have a column to specify the ordering.  If you did, then an `order by` would allow you to have an `identity` column that captures the ordering.  This would look like:

```
insert into t2(col1, col2)
    select col1, col2
    from data d cross apply
         (values (varchar1, varchar2, 1), (varchar3, varchar4, 2), (varchar5, varchar6, 3)
         ) v(col1, col2, priority)
    order by d.id, v.priority;
```

Comment: This actually works! I never used apply before. I would it do against larger data sets(30,000+ rows)?

Comment: @Maz . . . This should work quite well against larger data sets.